# Code is compiled successfully but not working in browser

Tags: angular

[image: Not secure https://localhost:4200/#/]

The browser is in blank tried all commands and nothing is working please give me any solution

Answer (score 1):

I see you're trying to access `https://localhost:4200` but you don't have a SSL certificate installed.
Try to change the url to `http://localhost:4200`.